# Difference between .score() and .predict in the sklearn library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have instantiated a SVC object using the sklearn library with the following code:

`clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, cache_size=1000, max_iter = -1, verbose = True)`

I then fit data to it using:

`model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Where X_train is a (301,60) and y_train is (301,) ndarray (y_train consisting of class labels "1", "2" and "3").

Now, before I stumbled across the .score() method, to determine the accuracy of my model on the training set i was using the following:

`prediction = np.divide((y_train == model.predict(X_train)).sum(), y_train.size, dtype = float)`

which gives a result of approximately 62%.

However, when using the model.score(X_train, y_train) method I get a result of approximately 83%.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why this should be the case because as far as I understand, they should return the same result?

ADDENDUM:

The first 10 values of y_true are:

- 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, ...

Whereas for y_pred (when using model.predict(X_train)), they are:

- 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, ...

Comment: That's weird, can you post some subset of your data (at least  some `y_true` and `y_pred` values)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `y_train` is `(301, 1)` and not `(301,)` numpy does broadcasting, so

```
(y_train == model.predict(X_train)).shape == (301, 301)
```

which is not what you intended.
The correct version of your code would be

```
np.mean(y_train.ravel() == model.predict(X_train))
```

which will give the same result as

```
model.score(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i was incorrect when stating the question, y_train is in fact a (301,) - my mistake (question has been edited)!

Comment: That being said, when using `np.mean(y_train.ravel() == model.predict(X_train))` I still get a training accuracy of 60ish percent. :(

Comment: What is shape and dtype of ``y_train``, ``X_train``, model.predict(X_train)`` and ``y_train == model.predict(X_train)``?

Comment: `y_train` : (301,) int64;
`X_train` : (301, 60) float64;
`model.predict(X_train)` : (301,) int64;
`y_train == model.predict(X_train)` : bool;

Does that help?

Comment: Is ``y_train == model.predict(X_train)`` just a bool or an array of dtype bool? If so, what is the shape?
This is really odd. Can you share the data?

Comment: `y_train == model.predict(X_train)` is a (301,) of dtype bool. I'll see what I can do about providing the data - unfortunately its a non-trivial process...

Comment: Turns out, due to a nuance in the way I way handling my data set, X_train was slightly modified between the two function calls, hence the discrepancy in the accuracy results. Thank you for your help and I apologise for sending you on a wild goose chase. Cheers!